# Proving $\left | f'(x) \right | \le C$ for all $x \in (a,b)$ for a Lipschitz function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is continuous and differentiable on $(a,b)$.  If $f$ is Lipschitz with constant $C$, show that $\left | f'(x) \right | \le C$ for all $x \in (a,b)$

I've already proven the 'other way', namely if $\left | f'(x) \right | \le C$ where $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is continuous and differentiable on $(a,b)$ then $f$ is Lipschitz with constant $C$, but I can't seem to work out this other direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x \in (a,b)$. Then, there's a neighbourhood $(x-\delta,x+\delta) \subset (a,b)$, and for all $y \in (x-\delta,x+\delta)$:

$$|f(y) - f(x)| \le C|y-x|$$

Hence:

$$\lim_{y\to x} \left|\frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-x} \right| \le C$$